# function in java err

Tags: javascript

I wrote a program with a pattern  that takes names and numbers from inputs and stores them in an array.
And I wrote a function that takes these contacts from the array and creates tags for each contact and puts the name and number of the contact inside these tags.
The problem is that in the `addbook` function I called the `showrecords` function, then every time the existing contact list is added, the contacts are updated and the contacts are shown, but when I use the `showrecords` function, it gives an error inside the `addbook` function, which is not available.
Please help me solve my problem

```js
function ElementBuilder(name) {
    this.element = document.createElement(name);

    this.appendSelector = function(selector) {
        this.appendElement = document.querySelector(selector).appendChild(this.element);
        return this
    };

    this.setAttribute = function(attribute, valueAttribute) {
        this.element.setAttribute(attribute, valueAttribute)
        return this;
    };

    this.addEventListener = function(event, fun) {
        this.element.addEventListener(event, fun);
        return this;
    };

    this.text = function(text) {
        this.element.textContent = text;
        return this;
    };

    this.build = function() {
        return this.element;
    };
}

const builder = {
    create: function(name) {
        return new ElementBuilder(name);
    }
};

function PhoneBookRecord(name, phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
}

function PhoneBook() {
    this.records = [];

    const selectID = (idName) => document.getElementById(idName);
    // function add contact
    this.addbook = function() {
        const self = this

        function add() {
            const letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
            const numbers = /^([0-9])+$/;
            if ((selectID("name").value.match(letters)) && (selectID("phone").value.match(numbers))) {
                const newContact = new PhoneBookRecord(selectID("name").value, selectID("phone").value);
                self.records.push(newContact);
 // The problem is that it cannot find this function until the contact list is displayed
                showrecords();

            }
            return add;
        }
    }
}
function Render(container) {
    this.container = container;
    const phoneBook = new PhoneBook()
    const add = phoneBook
        .addbook();
    const arry = phoneBook
        .records;
    // Function of elements Html
    this.init = function() {
        const btn = builder
            .create("button")
            .text("Add")
            .addEventListener("click", add)
            .setAttribute("id", "add")
            .appendSelector("div")
            .build();
        const phoneBookContact = builder
            .create("div")
            .setAttribute("id", "addBook")
            .appendSelector("div")
            .build();

        phoneBook.showrecords();
    };
    // Function: Read contacts from the array and display them
    this.showrecords = function() {
        const addBookId = document.getElementById('addBook');
        const index = 0;
        addBookId.innerHTML = '';
        arry.forEach(elm => {
            // Function of elements Html
            const nameContent = builder
                .create('li')
                .text(`${elm.name}`)
                .appendSelector("div>div")
                .build();

            const phoneContent = builder
                .create('li')
                .text(`${elm.phone}`)
                .appendSelector("div>div")
                .build();
        });

    }
}
const phoneBookContainer = document.getElementById("phone-book-container");
const app = new Render(phoneBookContainer);
app.init();
```

```html
    <form>
        <label>Phone Book</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name">
        <input type="number" placeholder="phone" id="phone">
    </form>
    <div id="phone-book-container"></div>
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the 

CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know how 

to delete your post, take a look at 
[**How does deleting work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

Answer (score 1):

These are the 2 steps i did to change the code and get to a working state.

1. Extract showrecords out of Render
2. pass the records to showrecords

I think this code needs a lot of work.
Here is a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jq5L7cdf/17/

Here is a snippet

```js
function showrecords(arry) {
        const addBookId = document.getElementById('addBook');
        const index = 0;
        addBookId.innerHTML = '';
        arry.forEach(elm => {
            // Function of elements Html
            const nameContent = builder
                .create('li')
                .text(`${elm.name}`)
                .appendSelector("div>div")
                .build();

            const phoneContent = builder
                .create('li')
                .text(`${elm.phone}`)
                .appendSelector("div>div")
                .build();
        });

    }

function ElementBuilder(name) {
    this.element = document.createElement(name);

    this.appendSelector = function(selector) {
        this.appendElement = document.querySelector(selector).appendChild(this.element);
        return this
    };

    this.setAttribute = function(attribute, valueAttribute) {
        this.element.setAttribute(attribute, valueAttribute)
        return this;
    };

    this.addEventListener = function(event, fun) {
        this.element.addEventListener(event, fun);
        return this;
    };

    this.text = function(text) {
        this.element.textContent = text;
        return this;
    };

    this.build = function() {
        return this.element;
    };
}

const builder = {
    create: function(name) {
        return new ElementBuilder(name);
    }
};

function PhoneBookRecord(name, phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
}

function PhoneBook() {
    this.records = [];

    const selectID = (idName) => document.getElementById(idName);
    // function add contact
    this.addbook = function() {
        const self = this
        function add() {

            const letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
            const numbers = /^([0-9])+$/;
            if ((selectID("name").value.match(letters)) && (selectID("phone").value.match(numbers))) {
                const newContact = new PhoneBookRecord(selectID("name").value, selectID("phone").value);
                self.records.push(newContact);
 // The problem is that it cannot find this function until the contact list is displayed
                showrecords(self.records);

            }
        }
            return add;
        
    }
}
function Render(container) {
    this.container = container;
    const phoneBook = new PhoneBook()
    const add = phoneBook
        .addbook();
    // Function of elements Html
    this.init = function() {
        const btn = builder
            .create("button")
            .text("Add")
            .addEventListener("click", add)
            .setAttribute("id", "add")
            .appendSelector("div")
            .build();
        const phoneBookContact = builder
            .create("div")
            .setAttribute("id", "addBook")
            .appendSelector("div")
            .build();

        showrecords(phoneBook.records); 
    };
    // Function: Read contacts from the array and display them
    this.showrecords =  showrecords
}
const phoneBookContainer = document.getElementById("phone-book-container");
const app = new Render(phoneBookContainer);
app.init();
```

```html
    <form>
        <label>Phone Book</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name">
        <input type="number" placeholder="phone" id="phone">
    </form>
    <div id="phone-book-container"></div>
```

## EDIT:

use showrecords from Render

```js
function ElementBuilder(name) {
    this.element = document.createElement(name);

    this.appendSelector = function(selector) {
        this.appendElement = document.querySelector(selector).appendChild(this.element);
        return this
    };

    this.setAttribute = function(attribute, valueAttribute) {
        this.element.setAttribute(attribute, valueAttribute)
        return this;
    };

    this.addEventListener = function(event, fun) {
        this.element.addEventListener(event, fun);
        return this;
    };

    this.text = function(text) {
        this.element.textContent = text;
        return this;
    };

    this.build = function() {
        return this.element;
    };
}

const builder = {
    create: function(name) {
        return new ElementBuilder(name);
    }
};

function PhoneBookRecord(name, phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
}

function PhoneBook() {
    this.records = [];

    const selectID = (idName) => document.getElementById(idName);
    // function add contact
    this.addbook = function() {
        const self = this
        function add() {

            const letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
            const numbers = /^([0-9])+$/;
            if ((selectID("name").value.match(letters)) && (selectID("phone").value.match(numbers))) {
                const newContact = new PhoneBookRecord(selectID("name").value, selectID("phone").value);
                self.records.push(newContact);
 // The problem is that it cannot find this function until the contact list is displayed

            }
        }
            return add;
        
    }
}
function Render(container) {
    this.container = container;
    const phoneBook = new PhoneBook()
    const add = phoneBook
        .addbook();
        
    this.addEntry = () => {
            add();
        this.showrecords();
    }   
    // Function of elements Html
    this.init = function() {
        const btn = builder
            .create("button")
            .text("Add")
            .addEventListener("click", this.addEntry)
            .setAttribute("id", "add")
            .appendSelector("div")
            .build();
        const phoneBookContact = builder
            .create("div")
            .setAttribute("id", "addBook")
            .appendSelector("div")

        this.showrecords(); 
    };
    // Function: Read contacts from the array and display them
    this.showrecords =  () => {
        const addBookId = document.getElementById('addBook');
        const index = 0;
        addBookId.innerHTML = '';
            const arry = phoneBook.records;
        arry.forEach(elm => {
            // Function of elements Html
            const nameContent = builder
                .create('li')
                .text(`${elm.name}`)
                .appendSelector("div>div")
                .build();

            const phoneContent = builder
                .create('li')
                .text(`${elm.phone}`)
                .appendSelector("div>div")
                .build();
        });

    }

}
const phoneBookContainer = document.getElementById("phone-book-container");
const app = new Render(phoneBookContainer);
app.init();
```

```html
    <form>
        <label>Phone Book</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name">
        <input type="number" placeholder="phone" id="phone">
    </form>
    <div id="phone-book-container"></div>
```

Comment: Why did you deleted the comments and unmarked answer?